# using moment in react native

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-native

when I import moment like:

`import * as moment from 'moment';`

I get the following error

`moment is not a function.`

When import it like:

`import moment from 'moment';`

I get the following error:

`External module 'moment' has no default export`

What is the best way to add moment to react native?

By the way I added moment by this command: `npm install --save moment`

I also used toLocaleDateString() before, it works on IOs but it doesn't work properly on android so I have to use moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `node_module` and `package.json` that you already have moment package. If you have all of these just remove `node_modules` and install all packages again.

Comment: I have moment both in `node_module` and `package.json`, I also remove `node_modules` and executed `npm install` still get same result

Comment: I wonder if you are running app by expo or browser if you use expo try to build again , sometime the package you install not loaded from hot reload of expo.

Comment: I use expo, I closed the app and start it again from command line, what do you mean by build it again?

Comment: i mean deleting android folder (probably ios too) , and run `react-native eject`
`react-native upgrade` (rebuilds android/ios folders)
`react-native link`
before you want to `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android`. Try this.

Answer (score 3):

1- first, install :

```
npm i moment
```

2- second import :

```
import moment from "moment";
```

3- then use and get the moment date :

```
const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {   
        
    // get current time 

     var date = moment().utcOffset('+03:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    // or get time ' hh:mm:ss a'

    setCurrentDate(date); 
 }, []);
```

4- finely use :

```
<Text style={styles.txtcurentDate}>Current Date:{currentDate}</Text >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import moment from "moment";
```

You have that right. If you are having problems with npm try running `npm install` in the root directory.

Comment: Are you by any chance using typescript?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `expo`, import moment as

```
let moment = require('moment');
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.